# "TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Probando una forma de introducir elementos de una lista por teclado, me sale este error.

```
lista = []
rango = int(input("Introduce el tamaño de la lista: "))
for i in range(0, rango-1):
    elem = int(input("Introduce el valor del elemento ", i, ": "))
    lista.append(elem)

print(lista)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `input()` sólo admite un parámetro (una cadena). En tu caso le pasas tres:

```
input("Introduce el valor del elemento ", i, ": ")
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear una sola cadena que contenga el valor de `i`, para lo que te puede ser útil `str.format()` así:

```
input("Introduce el valor del elemento {}: ".format(i))
```

o si usas Python 3.7+ usar los f-strings (observa la `f` antes de abrir comillas):

```
input(f"Introduce el valor del elemento {i}: ")
```